# How to delete in an XML document, a specific element according to the value of the child using PHP

Tags: php, xml

How do I delete all elements in a xml Product, if the element `<onlineShopVisibility>` value is `notVisibleOnline`?  In other words, I need to delete all Product that contain `<onlineShopVisibility>notVisibleOnline</onlineShopVisibility>` and save to a new file.

```xml
<response status="ok">
  <Product>
    <allowChangeOfPriceOnTheInvoice>true</allowChangeOfPriceOnTheInvoice>
    <allowChangeOfProductDescriptionOnTheInvoice>true</allowChangeOfProductDescriptionOnTheInvoice>
    <allowChangeOfVatRateOnTheInvoice>false</allowChangeOfVatRateOnTheInvoice>
    <costPosition />
    <currency>EUR</currency>
    <description>tralala ko imam</description>
    <exchangeRate>SlovenianBankMiddleRate</exchangeRate>
    <grossPrice>22.13</grossPrice>
    <isTrackedByLotNumbers>false</isTrackedByLotNumbers>
    <lastUpdateTimestamp>30.01.2021 17:07:34</lastUpdateTimestamp>
    <name>3D očala Philips PTA508</name>
    <onlineShopVisibility>notVisibleOnline</onlineShopVisibility>
    <procurementTransactionAccount>660000</procurementTransactionAccount>
    <productCode>3D OCALA 1</productCode>
    <productGroupPrimary />
    <productGroupSecondary />
    <retailPrice>27</retailPrice>
    <status>active</status>
    <trackItemsBySerialNumbers>false</trackItemsBySerialNumbers>
    <type>goodsWithStockManagement</type>
    <unit>kos</unit>
    <useOfPriceList>false</useOfPriceList>
    <vatPercentage>22</vatPercentage>
    <warrantyPeriod>0</warrantyPeriod>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    ...
    <onlineShopVisibility>VisibleOnline</onlineShopVisibility>
    ...
  </Product>
</response>
```

Code so far:

```
$toDelete = array ();
foreach ( $data1->Product as $item ) {
    $price = $item->onlineShopVisibility; 
    if ($price ="notVisibleOnline" ) { 
        $toDelete[] = $item; 
    } 
} 
foreach ($toDelete as $item) { 
    $dom = dom_import_simplexml($item); 
    $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom); 
} 
echo $data1; 
file_put_contents('artikli.xml', $data1);
```

Comment: Have you managed to get as far as loading the XML file?

Comment: yes i don't know then further delete the item

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code you already have that we can help you to improve it.

Comment: `$price ="notVisibleOnline"` is assigning the value, `$price == "notVisibleOnline"` is a comparison

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work either, I also tried ===

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're converting each node to DOM. However you could use DOM directly.

```
// bootstrap the DOM 
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load($xmlFile);

// fetch nodes using an xpath expression 
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$products = $xpath->evaluate('//Product[onlineShopVisibility="notVisibleOnline"]');

// iterate nodes
foreach ($products as $product) {
    // remove node
    $product->parentNode->removeChild($product);
}

$document->save($xmlFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the change from `=` to `==`,

```
if ($price == "notVisibleOnline" ) {
```

you also need to save the file as the source of `$data1` using `asXML()`, at the moment you are trying to write the object out...

```
file_put_contents('artikli.xml', $data1->asXML());
```

Comment: if i use i get error 500 and it doesn't create the file, otherwise it creates a file for me but with all the elements my file is 12 MB

Comment: You would need to find out what the error says, at the moment it's difficult for me to know what is failing.